# Advertising the Site

Tags: discussion

I came across the following: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/community-promotion-ads-2015

Wondering if there is and interest to promote our site in other SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

We can't at the moment: that feature is available only to "graduated" (not "beta") sites.

It's one of the "perks" of graduation.

Comment: Following is just a proposal: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/2671

Comment: ELL is promoting a site which is still not even a beta site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning?referrer=sg-MbJAGOjNnNFDS7ptHjQ2 as in 2nd site from top they are promoting. I think it is we cannot promote but other sites but graduated sites can promote us if they agree. Perhaps we need to double check this. If so the main question would be which site will agree to carry our proposal. But any way only if there is interest from other to do this.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala I think maybe you're right: you could post an ad for our site [there](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2635), and then if they upvoted it then they would see that ad on their site. Normally, maybe it's the ELL community (I don't know whether that includes you) who suggest what ads they want to see on their site. FWIW our site is already advertised network-wide sometimes, by one of our topics appearing in the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) list.